# Including a .metal file that just defines a function causes fragment shader app to run slow

Tags: ios, kernel, metal

If I include a `.metal` file with just these three lines in my app with other `.metal` files, a fragment shader in the app runs about 10x slower, even though the code in the `.metal` file is not used anywhere and the two `.metal` files are completely unrelated:

```
#include <metal_stdlib>
using namespace metal;

kernel void myKernel(texture2d<half> detailTexture [[texture(0)]]) {}
```

When the above `.metal` file is included, in the frame capture this warning is shown:

> Shader "fragment_particle" in pipeline "RenderPipelineState 0x122847a00" exceeded the available number of registers and data was spilled into slower GPU memory. (144 bytes)  Issue
> reduce function’s register usage to avoid costly spills. reduce stack memory usage

If I include these three lines instead, the fragment shader in the app works as expected and the warning above is not shown:

```
#include <metal_stdlib>
using namespace metal;

kernel void myKernel() {}
```

Changing the name of the function or texture does not help.

If I put the three lines in the `.metal` file with the fragment shader, all is well.

What could be causing this?

Comment: Sounds like a bug, honestly. Did you try filing a bug using Apple's Feedback Assistant?

Comment: Seems like a bug, but I wanted get some feedback before submitting a report.